# Where to get the public key for the JWT authentication token in Firebase projects?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, jwt, firebase-admin

I am creating a JWT token using the firebase admin sdk like this:

```
const app = initializeApp();
getAuth().createCustomToken(uid, myAdditionalClaims);
```

I get this token without ever creating a key-pair. It seams to be a preconfigured key-pair.

I would like to send the token to a third party app. But the app needs to verify the token, so it needs the public key.

Where do I get the public key?

I do not need it programmatically. It would be enough to know where to find it in a admin console.

Answer (score -2):

1. Log in to the Firebase console for your project.
2. Click on the "Settings" gear icon in the sidebar on the left.
3. Navigate to the "Service Accounts" tab.
4. Under "Firebase Admin SDK" section, click on the "Generate New
   Private Key" button to download a new service account private key in
   JSON format.
5. Open the downloaded JSON file and find the "private_key" field. This
   is the RSA private key that can be used to verify the JWT tokens
   generated by Firebase Authentication.

Comment: But for verification you need the public key, because the token was signed with the private key.

Comment: Look this https://www.tonyvu.co/posts/jwt-authentication-node-js

Comment: This explains how to create a new key-pair. But I don't need a new key pair. The example code in the question works without me to create a key. It uses a preconfigured key-pair. The question is, where do I find the public key of this preconfigured key-pair.

Comment: use this link
https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: There are two keys. Which one is it?

Comment: I think both, need to try

Comment: @Witek if you inspect the token on https://jwt.io, do you see a "kid" (Key Id) which is identical to one of the numbers in above link (the one with the two certificates?

Comment: The JWT has no "kid" field -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75825220/why-is-kid-missing-in-jwt-created-by-firebase-admin-sdk

Comment: You generate the token using the firebase private key. You can use nodejs, php etc to generate the token. When you accessed firebase service you send with the rest request the token 'bearer token" and Firebase will authenticate using the public key that is stored in your firebase account when you generate and download the private key