# Why is "kid" missing in JWT created by Firebase Admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I create a JWT token using firebase admin sdk on a cloud function like this:

```js
const app = initializeApp();
getAuth().createCustomToken(uid, myAdditionalClaims);
```

Now a third party App needs to verify the token like described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library

But there is no `kid` header field. Only header fields are these:

```json
{"alg": "RS256", "typ": "JWT"}
```

So how do I get the `kid` in there? Or how to verify without `kid`?

I found a hint, that `auth.currentUser.getIdToken()` should be used instead of `auth.createCustomToken()`. But I also need custom claims inside the token and `getIdToken()` does not support custom claims.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase ID Tokens (or *access tokens*) are generated when a user is authenticated successfully and can be used for checking user's authorization. 
Custom Tokens on the other hand are used to sign in/authenticate the user at first place and are generally used when you have your own legacy authentication mechanism.

Your server verifies the ID tokens that contain `kid` claim and not the custom tokens.

---

> I found a hint, that auth.currentUser.getIdToken() should be used instead of auth.createCustomToken(). But I also need custom claims inside the token and getIdToken() does not support custom claims.

`createCustomToken()` method is present in Firebase Admin SDK and not client SDK. You must use `getIdToken()` on client side to get user's token and verify that on your backend.

Comment: Problem is that createCustomToken() supports a custom claim object and getIdToken() does not. So how do I get my custom claim object into the token?